# Including different versions of the same class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I lost most of this afternoon tracking down a bug which basically came down to including two different versions of the same header file declaring the same class in Visual Studio 2015.  Greatly simplified, it appears as follows;

**oldcamera.h**

```
#pragma once

class camera
{
public:
 camera();
 int a;
 double x,y,z;
};
```

**camera.h**

```
#pragma once

class camera
{
public:
 camera();
 double x,y,z;
};
```

**camera.cpp**

```
#include camera.h

camera::camera()
{
  x = y = 0;
  z = 1;
};
```

**mytransclass.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "oldcamera.h"

class trans
{
public:
   camera m_camera;
};
```

**func.cpp**

```
#include "mytransclass.h"

void MyFunc(trans *ptrans)
{
  ptrans->x = 1.0;
  ptrans->y = 2.0;
  ptrans->z = 3.0;
}
```

The project includes camera.cpp and func.cpp, and when single stepping through MyFunc, the debugger showed the assignments weren't actually doing anything.  Question is whether this should compile and link without warning, and if it is legal (which knowing the convoluted heritage of c++ is likely), why does the assignment fail?  If it is legal, is there any way to flag it as an error? Compiler is Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: What happened to the include guards?

Comment: @Ed heal, #pragma once in both, I'll edit the question to reflect this

Comment: what was in oldcamera.cpp?

Comment: @David, pretty much the same as in camera.cpp, but it wasn't included in the project.  If it had been it would have ended up as a simple duplicate symbol error in the linker.

Comment: Have you done a clean followed by a build - aka start from scratch

Comment: Are the two `camera` classes different or the same, as in your example?

Comment: @Ed heal, yes and on VS2013 as well as I thought it might be a VS2015 issue

Comment: @AntonSavin, the two camera classes are largely the same but not identical.  Basically, i developed the class in a separate standalone application that worked as a test bed / prototype, and changed the file to include a different stdafx.h to be compatible with my main project.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin That is very very relevant, and the reason this is broken

Comment: @David, I'm well aware that is the reason it is broken, just wondering why it didn't flag a compiler warning and whether it is even legitimate.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin you should demonstrate in your example that the 2 versions of Camera are different. If they were identical, this would work.

Comment: @David, question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `#include` something you're basically copying and pasting that file into where you `#include`d. It's not actually an error to have multiple of the same class definition, as long they are not multiple of the same class definition being included into the same compilation unit (cpp). If you do that, it breaks the one definition rule.

In your setup, the functions in the version of Camera in oldcamera.h are calling the functions written for camera.h (since those functions are the only which were compiled, since you said oldcamera.cpp wasn't in the project). However, those functions rely on the data layout of the class Camera being a certain way. Since `oldcamera.h`'s `Camera` and new `camera.h`'s `Camera` have a different data layout (which you didn't demonstrate, but I'm assuming), shit hits the fan.

Answer (score 1):

Your program violates [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), which in particular says ([basic.def.odr]/6):

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), ... in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
>   such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>   (6.1) — each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens
>   ...
>   If the definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.